# Data recovery in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 13.04, data-recovery

I have a hp laptop with Windows 8 installed. I couldn't run both, Ubuntu and Windows, so I removed Windows and installed Ubuntu 13.04.

On July 10th, 2015 I replaced the previous version with Ubuntu 14.04 (clean install, not upgraded).

I had a very important folder with .tex files in Ubuntu 13.04. Recovery tools in Ubuntu gave only 14.04 files. If I reinstall Windows 8, can I recover these files with any advanced recovery tools?

Please help, these are very important files for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need not install Windows again to recover your files. There are many utilities available in Ubuntu which will scan your hard disk partitions for deleted files and restore them. Such a list is available [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery). I have one particular program called Photorec in mind. It comes bundled with a package called 
    testdisk

For more instructions in installing Photorec, please go through this [link](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step).
Be sure to select **.tex** file extension in photorec and proceed further.

Comment: *Recovery tools in ubuntu gave only 14.04 files.* I guess that means SHIVA already tried the most commonly used recovery tool in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I don't think he tried all of them, only those which he knew of. Also I don't understand what he is talking about when he says 14.04 files. Any scan of deleted files in the hard disk will return all files, irrespective of which OS they had existed in, unless of course you completely wipe the hard disk when switching OSes. Then again, normal users don't do the above unless they know what they are doing, in which case he wouldn't have asked this question.

Comment: I didn't say he tried ALL of them, but testdisk is the most commonly used recovery tool in Ubuntu and if he tried ANY recovery tool in Ubuntu, I guess testdisk is the one he already tried.

Comment: Lets wait and see for the OP to reply. That will tell us what he tried and what he didn't.

Comment: SHIVA is not an unregistered user. Unregistered users have a higher probability than usual of being bots. That means the probability that SHIVA will come back and check his question is fairly high.

Answer (score 0):

I have used testdisk to recover(ext partition 4). 14.04 files means it recovered files deleted after 10th July(14.04). It didn't recover files in 13.04(before 10th July). My required  folder was in 13.04 and it had .tex files and .c files. If I could recover atleast .c files, then it will be useful to me.